# How can I get Alien Isolation to work?

Tags: games, steam

I have Alien Isolation installed on a fresh Ubuntu 16.10 system. When I attempt to run the game from Steam in the terminal, I am presented with a loading display from the game and the game's mouse pointer and then the game simply crashes.

How can I investigate this further?

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
- RAM: 8 GiB

The terminal log I see is a follows:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",    
(steam:3873): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Unknown device type 14    
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Could not create object for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2: unknown object type    
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'secondaries'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'secondaries'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'secondaries'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'autoconnect-priority'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'secondaries'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'secondaries'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'secondaries'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'autoconnect-priority'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'
** (steam:3873): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311.30 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
roaming config store loaded successfully - 749 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
ExecCommandLine: ""/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam" "steam://run/214490" "
ExecSteamURL: "steam://run/214490"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
System startup time: 3.86 seconds
(steam:3873): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/glib2.0-6SKPi7/glib2.0-2.50.2/./gobject/gsignal.c:2523: signal 'child-added' is invalid for instance '0x582f60e8' of type 'GtkMenu'
Game update: AppID 214490 "Alien: Isolation", ProcID 3976, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 3976 for game ID 214490
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 3977 for game ID 214490
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 3978 for game ID 214490
>>> Adding process 3980 for game ID 214490
>>> Adding process 3981 for game ID 214490
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 214490
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198033155866 [API loaded no]
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(20170119012220)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
ExecCommandLine: "/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/driverhelperready"
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/driverhelperready"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/user/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Game crashed, if possible email [support@feralinteractive.com] with the crash file [/home/user/.local/share/feral-interactive/AlienIsolation/crashes/1d1ad3e1-d726-af0e-70f3e23a-64683eb9.dmp] and details
Game removed: AppID 214490 "Alien: Isolation", ProcID 3981
```

Comment: Run `steam` in a terminal and start your game. Once it crashes you should see an error in the terminal. Also giving your CPU GPU and ram would help.

Comment: @MarkKirby Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the terminal output and hardware details.

Comment: It says you can find the crash log here `/home/user/.local/share/feral-interactive/AlienIsolation/crashes/1d1ad3e1-d726-af0e-70f3e23a-64683eb9.dmp` add it to the question or, if it is really long put it on something like http://pastebin.com and link it here

Comment: @MarkKirby Yes, I saw that. It is just a binary file, so I can't see it.

Comment: Is this a laptop with an Nvidia graphics chip?

Comment: @MarkKirby No, it has Intel Graphics, but the game has run on the same machine with a previous install of Ubuntu and a previous install of the game, so it is a software issue.